# Android, Get gallery image and store in integer

Tags: android, image, integer, gallery

I am working on fetching images from gallery and i want to store the image selected in a integer. 
I have tried everything but nothing is helping me, 
my code is

```
private void getGalleyImage() {
    Intent fileChooserIntent = new Intent();
    fileChooserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    fileChooserIntent.setType("image/*");
    fileChooserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(fileChooserIntent, "Select Picture"), 1);

}
```

i am getting images but i am not able to store that image in integer, i have tried uri and bitmap then bytearray, 
I want to store them in integer.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is that you want to store in an integer? some sort of image id or the actual image data (which obviously won't fit in an integer) ?

Comment: image id, and then i want to pass that id to next activity